# How to REPLACE INTEGERS on the index row of a dataframe WITH TIME INTERVAL using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, time-series

Here is the data frame and I want to change the integers 1-74 to time intervals starting from 5:00 to 24:00 with 15 minutes intervals. The integers will be mapped thus (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 72, 73, 74) to (5:30, 5:45, 6:00, 6:15, ..., 23:30, 23:45, 24:00).[image: screeshot of dataframe]

I'm expecting a result like this. I have done it manually using excel functions. I need a way to do it with python f[image: screenshot from excel]unctions.

Comment: 24:00. Is it a valid time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.date_range`:

```
df.columns = pd.date_range('5:30', freq='15T', periods=len(df.columns)).strftime('%H:%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the time series and replace the column names.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

data.columns = [(dt.strptime('5:30', '%H:%M') + i * timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%H:%M') for i in range(75)]
```